# Fusion table request quota exceeded

Tags: api, request, google-fusion-tables

I have a Fusion table and updating it via Java client API. Now I am getting the error below:

> Request failed for http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?
>   sql=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx returned code 400. Server response: `<HTML> <HEAD> <TITLE>Request Quota Exceeded</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Request Quota Exceeded</H1> <H2>Error 400</H2> </BODY> </HTML>`

I am bit confused in the above error that what is exact meaning of **"Request Quota"**? How can I overcome this?

Also, how can I calculate the total number of requests sent by me?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#quota

Comment: IS adding/editing rows in fusion table UI directly counted as a request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the deprecated API, which is in the process of being turned down. You should upgrade as soon as possible. See the announcement here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fusion-tables-users-group/ADmyZI8ax6M/PH1YCDnbqtAJ